# Running the sample code in pytesseract

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am running python 2.6.6 and want to install the [pytesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract) package. After extraction and installation, I can call the pytesseract from the command line. However I want to run the tesseract within python. I have the following code (ocr.py):

```
try:
     import Image
except ImportError:
     from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test-european.jpg'),lang='fra'))
```

When I run the code by python ocr.py, I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ocr.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
  File "/pytesseract-0.1.6/build/lib/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 164, in image_to_string
    raise TesseractError(status, errors)
pytesseract.TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: python tesseract.py [-l language] input_file')
```

test.png and test-european.jpg are in the working directory. Can Someone help me running this code?
I have tried the following:

1. Adjusted the tesseract_cmd to 'pytesseract'
2. Installed tesseract-ocr

Any help is appreciated as I am trying to solve this problem for hours now.

Comment: Does `tesseract test.png stdout` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tesseract_cmd` should point to the command line program [`tesseract`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract), not `pytesseract`.

For instance on Ubuntu you can install the program using:

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

And then set the variable to just `tesseract` or `/usr/bin/tesseract`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case it was in the '/usr/local/bin/tesseract'